# Is there any reason to use button elements instead of span elements?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Something I find really annoying in Chrome is that when you click a button, it retains focus after the click. This means that after clicking on a bootstrap button, it remains dark grey (the hover/click color).

I don't think this looks good and may be confusing for users, so I just tried using span elements with btn btn-default btn-xs classes instead of using button elements. It seems to work fine, but is this OK to do, or is there any reason why I should use button elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only issue I can think of is accessibility.  I don't know how a screen reader would be able to interpret a span tag as something clickable.  That said, there are probably ways you could mark it up with aria tags to make it more clear.  Actually, the doc prescribes using the button classes on anchor tags as well, but if you aren't passing an href the span tag might make more sense assuming again, that you can mark it up for accessibility.

**EDIT:**
The very first example here describes how to use role="button" within a span tag:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_button_role